# Vue Webpack Build Breaks Bulma CSS

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js, bulma

I scaffold a webpack template for my vue project using the vue-cli. Subsequently, I added Bulma's CSS. When I run the program normally (npm run dev), the CSS renders properly. However, upon building the project for production (npm run build) with the default webpack configuration, the styling of the web app is now misaligned. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

For comparison:

[Production Build of Vue with broken CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc6qR.png)

[Dev version of Vue rendering CSS properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFZGZ.png)

The following is my webpack config (webpack.prod.conf.js)

```js
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as yours. After some debugging, I realize that this is due to the order of css rules. It seems that the built css file doesn't have the same rules order as the dev server.

I searched a little bit on this topic. On the webpack documentation I have found this:

> Keep in mind that it’s difficult to manage the execution order of modules, so design your stylesheets so that order doesn’t matter. (You can, however, rely on the order within a given CSS file.)

I solved my problem by increasing the specificity of my custom css selectors by using `#id` instead of `.class`.

ex:

```
// my custom css rules
#navbar a {
  color: white
}
```

instead of:

```
// my custom css rules
.navbar a {
  color: white
}
```

Thus the order of your custom rules versus the bulma ones won't matter because the priority will be always for the `id` over the `class` selector.

I hope this is useful